# Editing a question in base of an answer

Tags: support, questions, answers

Suppose someone ask a question, then in base of the answer I gave, he/she change the question to something else. Now the my answer is meaningless looking like a copy of a part of the question. What am I supposed to do? Should I delete the answer?

Comment: No, the question should be rolled back to the previous revision, and the new question should be asked as a new post, provided the necessary research has been done by the asker.